# How to join JS objects inside an array? Onliner

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What ONELINER could I use to join ANY number of objects inside of an array? The repeated values should be placed inside a nested array, like so:

I have this input:

```js
[
    {a: 123},
    {b: "abc", c: 455},
    {d: null, c: 01, b: {}}
]
```

I should get this result:

```js
{
    a: 123,
    b: ["abc", {}],
    c: [455, 01],
    d: null
}
```

I have tried this, but no results :(

```js
my_array.map(function(x) {
    var result = {};
    for(var i in x) {
        result[i] = x[i];
    }
    return result;
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array of objects. Inside, loop through keys of the each object. If the accumulator doesn't have the key, add it. If the key already exists, use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create an array of values. `[].concat(acc[k], v)` will handle if `acc[k]` is an array or a single value.

```js
const input = [
    {a: 123},
    {b: 2222, c: 455},
    {d: null, c: 01}
]

const output = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(k))
      acc[k] = [].concat(acc[k], v)
    else
      acc[k] = v
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Here's a ES5 version of the above answer:

```js
var input = [
    {a: 123},
    {b: 2222, c: 455},
    {d: null, c: 01}
]

var output = input.reduce(function(acc, o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(k))
      acc[k] = [].concat(acc[k], o[k])
    else
      acc[k] = o[k]
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you @adiga!! This works! I see that you use es6 syntax, could you please transform into es5?